# Failed to start Docker in ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I Tried to start docker in amazon server using the following command sudo systemctl start docker,But I am getting below command sudo: systemctl: command not found

Answer (score 1):

try this step:-

```
 sudo service docker start
```

to check the status of service

```
sudo service docker status
```

**Reason**: systemctl command is not supported in your instance. You can use service command instead of systemctl command.

check what Amazon linux version you have runnng on using the command cat `/etc/os-release`.

If it is Amazon Linux Version 2, then i`t does support systemd and comes installed by default.`

If it is Amazon linux version 1, then `it doesn't support` cause Amazon Linux is ultimately based on an old version of CentOS/RHEL.

> if it is version 1, you just need to switch to any other linux distribution that supports system. **You can't yum install systemd like a package**

Comment: Now can able to start docker ,but what is this command systemctl why you ignore this

Comment: I start this command sudo service hydra start

But getting this 

An insecure configuration was detected. Please correct the following issues.
Error: TLS is enabled, however the issuance secret has been left to its default empty value. Please provide a value in the issuance_secret field.

Comment: is this a second question? you can ask it as a separate question.
and please accept this answer as a solution to your problem so that it may help others, thank you :)